# How to implement facebook share functionality in react.js?

Tags: facebook, reactjs

I want to implement facebook share functionality in react.js. Now the issue is I can't add meta tags dynamically in the react.js as the head tag is out of scope. Any one can help me regarding this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am looking for same thing, I tried react-share npm it works but it didn't share images and didn't share post like we can do using HTML, I need to share webmaster sharing using react.do you able to achieve this???